# Como regresar a la vista anterior Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

Como puedo regresar a la vista anterior pero cuando ya regrese.
ejemplo con flechas y puntitos:

Estoy aqui º

y me regreso con `[_controladorSuite.controladorDeNavegacion popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];`

como regreso de donde me regrese XD

----> o

o <-   o

o ->   o

jajajaja algo así es lo que quiero hacer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberías usar letras o números...

---> A

A <- B

A -> B

En cualquier caso, una vez haces pop de B, ya no puedes volver al mismo B. Necesitarás crear una nueva instancia de B y hacer push.

Además, si lo que quieres (en a <- B) es volver al controlador inmediatamente anterior, deberías usar `popViewController` en lugar de `popToRootViewController`.

En este caso coincide que tu rootViewController es también el inmediatamente anterior a B, pero te podría ocurrir esto:

A - B - C
`popToRootViewController`:  A <- C (sólo quedaría A)
`popViewController`: A - B <- C (quedaría B y por detrás estaría aún A)

Comment: y como hago eso  xD  desde la instancia ?

Comment: Desde el navigationController `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`